# Improving performance for WRITE operation on Oracle DB in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, soap, jdbc

I've a typical scenario & need to understand best possible way to handle this, so here it goes -

I'm developing a solution that will retrieve data from a remote SOAP based web service & will then push this data to an Oracle database on network.
Also, this will be a scheduled task that will execute every 15 minutes.

I've event queues on remote service that contains the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations that have been done since last retrieval, & once I retrieve the events for last 15 minutes, it again add events for next retrieval.

Now, its just pushing data to Oracle so all my interactions are INSERT & UPDATE statements.

There are around 60 tables on Oracle with some of them having 100+ columns. Moreover, for every 15 minutes cycle there would be around 60-70 Inserts, 100+ Updates & 10-20 Deletes.

This will be an executable jar file that will terminate after operation & will again start on next 15 minutes cycle.

So, I need to understand how should I handle WRITE operations (best practices) to improve performance for this  application as whole ?

Current Test Code (on every cycle) -

- Connects to remote service to get events.
- Creates a connection with DB (single connection object).
- Identifies the type of operation (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) & table on which it is done.
- After above, calls the respective method based on type of operation & table.
- Uses Preparedstatement with positional parameters, & retrieves each column value from remote service & assigns that to statement parameters.
- Commits the statement & returns to get event class to process next event.
- Above is repeated till all the retrieved events are processed after which program closes & then starts on next cycle & everything repeats again.

Thanks for help !

Comment: Have you considered what will happen if your initial operations haven't completed in 15 minutes and your executable starts again?

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting or updating one row at a time,You can consider executing a batch Insert or a batch Update. It has been proven that if you are attempting to update or insert rows after a certain quantity, you get much better performance.

Comment: thanks for reply, but my issue is with each event my SQL statement changes based on type of operation & table on which it needs to be done... other solution I thought was to add all similar events in Arraylist & then after all events are added, the use these arraylists to retrieve values & push to Oracle, but that will have a lot of lists for each specific type of event, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

The number of DB operations you are talking about (200 every 15 minutes) is tiny and will be easy to finish in less than 15 minutes. Some concrete suggestions:

You should profile your application to understand where it is spending its time. If you don't do this, then you don't know what to optimize next and you don't know if something you did helped or hurt.

If possible, try to get all of the events in one round-trip to the remote server.

You should reuse the connection to the remote service (probably by using a library that supports connection persistence and reuse).

You should reuse the DB connections by using a connection pooling library rather than creating a new connection for each insert/update/delete. Believe it or not, creating the connection probably takes 100+ times as long as doing your DB operation once you have the connection in hand.

You should consider doing multiple (or all) of the database operations in the same transaction rather than creating a new transaction for each row that is changed. However, you should carefully consider your failure modes such that you don't lose any events (if that is an important consideration).

You should consider utilizing prepared statement caching. This may help, but maybe not if Oracle is configured properly.

You should consider trying to analyze your operations to find any that can be batched together. This can be a lot faster if you have some "hot" operations that get done often.

Comment: To a certain extent, yes, it's tiny - read could be executed in less than a second. However, this very much depends on the architecture of the database. If it's at all big and you're missing an index it could take hours....

Comment: Oracle will cache statements for you.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/stmtcach.htm#g1079466  Additionally, oracle's implicit connection caching in 11g works very well (avoid ucp until 12.2). http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/concache.htm#JJDBC28685

Answer (score 0):

> "I've a typical scenario"

No you haven't.   You have a bespoke architecture, with a unique data model, unique data and unique business requirements.  That's not a bad thing, it's the state of pretty much every computer system that's not been bought off-the-shelf (and even some of them).

So, it's an experiment and you must approach it as such.  There is no "best practice".   Try various things and see what works best.

> "need to understand best possible way to handle this"

You will improve your chances of success enormously by hiring somebody who understands Oracle databases.